# ASP.net MVC 3 EntityType 'PaMap' has no key defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, primary-key

I am new to MVC 3 and all I am trying to do is create a CRUD interface with an existing DB. I keep recieving an error

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'PaMap' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'PaMaps' is based on    type 'PaMap' that has no keys defined.
```

The DB I am working with has three fields. PA_ID the primary key which I defined in MS SQL SERVER and refreshed multiple times to be sure it was actually defined. I also added the _ID part after reading about how sometimes MVC isn't happy unless your primary key had ID in the name. After this I saved and refreshed but still no luck. The category and the name are the other two columns in the table. I am using the code-first method so I instantiated my getters and setters in the PaMap class. I also tried setting the primary key in the PaMap class as well using the [key] method. All I get is another error

> "Invalid object name 'dbo.PaMaps'".

I searched the answers for this error as well and all I could find is to do a search and replace for dbo, I did that and there was only one spot where it used dbo but once I removed dbo the program would no longer run.

Right now I would be happy if I could get something to display from the DB but at the moment MVC is lying to my face about a primary key not being defined.

Can anyone help I can show you code if it would help diagnose the problem any faster? I have looked online almost everywhere for the answer to this question with no luck. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your web.config have in it for the database connections?  Are you using SQL Server Compact Edition, or some other version of SQL Server?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server R2 2008, thank you for your reply I will work through those examples and post again later today

Comment: I tried that walkthrough that you told me about Jennifer unfortunatly it did not work for me either because I messed it up or because I am using MS SQL Server 2008. I did manage to find another Tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489. This actually worked with my MS SQL Server 2008 DB to display the data in list form from the DB now I just need to figure out how to edit and delete! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best examples I've found for setting up MVC3 Code First with SQL Server Compact Edition are Walkthrough 2 here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

and for setting up the data migrations, this post here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

These were written with different versions of the product.. In Scott Gu's Walkthrough 2  (top link above), skip Step 2, since this is now part of EntityFramework, which gets referenced in all MVC 3 projects.  When you get to Step 7, depending on the version of SQL Server Compact Edition you have, you may not have the Edm Metadata table.  Don't just delete the Migrations tables if your version has them.  You'll need it.  This is where the Migrations (second link above) part comes in.

These were the best examples I could find when I was learning this, so I hope this helps.